# jQuery Autocomplete using Ajax won't parse

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I'm trying to use a basic autocomplete with ajax. I'm having trouble making sense of the results. I'm relatively new to jQuery so I apologize for my syntax, I'm better at PHP.

```
$("#category_title").autocomplete({
  source: function (request, response) {
    $.ajax({
       url: 'index.php?controller=AdminEvents&action=AutoComplete&variable=asdf',
       type: 'GET',
       success: function(data){
         response(data);
       }
    });
  },
  minLength: 2
});
```

The response from the controller is sample data, doesn't actually get anything from a database yet:

```
if ($this->isXHR())
{
  //$response = "{value1:test, value2:test2}";
  $response['value1'] = "test";
  $response['value2'] = "test2";
  $json = json_encode($response);
  print($json);
}
```

Here's the part that's strange to me.. basically, this works and the autocomplete box pops up, but here's what it does with the return:

[image]

Why?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#zipsearch').autocomplete({source:'suggest_zip.php', minLength:2});
});
```

**PHP**

```
$response = array();
$response[0]=array('label'=>'test','value'=>'test');
$response[1]=array('label'=>'test2','value'=>'test2');
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Same result from this.

Comment: Here is an example, check it, it works. http://www.htmlblog.us/jquery-autocomplete

Comment: See, I tried to adopt what I THOUGHT you were trying to say, I have no interest in replacing everything I've written to 'solve it'. I want to figure out what's wrong so I can understand.

Answer (score 0):

May be this helps you

**jquery**

```
$("#zipsearch").autocomplete({
                    source: function(req,res) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "index.php?controller=AdminEvents&action=AutoComplete&variable=asdf",
                            dataType: "json",
                            type: "GET",
                            data: {
                                term: req.term
                            },
                            success: function(data) {
                                res($.map(data, function(item) {
                                    return {
                                        label: item.value1,
                                        value: item.value1
                                    };
                                }));
                            },
                            error: function(xhr) {
                                alert(xhr.status + ' : ' + xhr.statusText);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$response=array();
$response[0]['value1'] = "test";
$response[1]['value1'] = "test2";
print json_encode($response);
?>
```