# jquery auto complete is not showing result

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am using jquery auto complete to get current data from database in php. But, I am not getting result.

Here is the code sample:

```
<label class="col-md-4">Referrer</label>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <input type="text" name="referrer" id='referrer' placeholder="Type keyword..." autocomplete="off" value="" class="form-control" />
</div>

<script>
var path = $( "#referrer" ).data('path');
$("#referrer").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/ajax/ir_populate_referrer",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                keyword: request.term,
                path: path
            },
            success: function(data) {
                response($.map(data, function(item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.label
                    }
                }));
            }
        })
    }
});
</script>
```

As in my search.php file:

```
<?php
    echo json_encode(array('label'=> $link, 'value' => $keyword));
?>
```

Comment: What is the result of data variable on source param function?

Comment: to debug problems with ajax, the best solution for me is FireBug for FF

Comment: did you try to write .php? (url: "/ajax/ir_populate_referrer.php")  
 try to see what fail returns $.ajax().fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {} )

Comment: May be this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23301478/jquery-autocomplete-using-ajax-wont-parse/23301669?noredirect=1#comment35675824_23301669

Comment: What is at the other end of `/ajax/ir_populate_referrer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**html**

```
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>test jquery autocomplete</title> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript"> 

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#zipsearch").autocomplete({
                    source: function(req,res) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "json.php",
                            dataType: "json",
                            type: "GET",
                            data: {
                                term: req.term
                            },
                            success: function(data) {
                                res($.map(data, function(item) {
                                    return {
                                        label: item.label,
                                        value: item.value
                                    };
                                }));
                            },
                            error: function(xhr) {
                                alert(xhr.status + ' : ' + xhr.statusText);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });

        </script> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css" /> 
        <style type="text/css">
        </style> 
    </head> 

    <body> 

        <form onsubmit="return false;"> 
            Ejemplo<br/>
            Enter a Zipcode:
            <input id="zipsearch" type="text" /> 
        </form>
    </body> 
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$response = array();
$response[0]=array('label'=>'test','value'=>'test');
$response[1]=array('label'=>'test2','value'=>'test2');
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```