# jQuery Autocomplete JSON

Tags: jquery, json

I am new to Stackoverflow. First time having a problem and I need some help.

I have a method that echo:

```
[{"label":"Paris - London - Rome","value":"1"},{"label":"Lison - Dublin - Berlin","value":"2"},{"label":"Atena - Paris - Warsaw","value":"4"},{"label":"Moscow - New York - San Francisco","value":"7"}]
```

My HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="auto" name="label"/>
<input name="tr" type="hidden"/>
```

My JS:

```
$(".auto").autocomplete({
        source : function(request, response) {
            $.get(url, function(data) {
                var source = eval(data);
                response(source);
            })
        },
        minLength : 2,
        select : function(event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
            this.value = ui.item.label;
            $(this).next().val(ui.item.value);
        }
    });
```

It works, but if I type Rome. It shows me all options instead of Paris - London - Rome.

If put the json to source it works properly. The code below works as it should, but the one above don't.

```
$(".auto").autocomplete({
        source : [{"label":"Paris - London - Rome","value":"1"},{"label":"Lison - Dublin - Berlin","value":"2"},{"label":"Atena - Paris - Warsaw","value":"4"},{"label":"Moscow - New York - San Francisco","value":"7"}],
        minLength : 2,
        select : function(event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
            this.value = ui.item.label;
            $(this).next().val(ui.item.value);
        }
    });
```

I think it might be something with that response ? or with eval?

I am not an expert.

Comment: Why `eval()`? Wouldn't `$.getJSON()` work better?

Comment: I just tried $.getJSON instead of $.get and I got rig of eval and I just put response(data) and the option list doesn't come up when I type something

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505160/jquery-auto-complete-is-not-showing-result/23505665#23505665

Comment: Actually it works. But still shows me the list with all options and if I type Rome it still shows all options .

Comment: @AlexanderCeballos I look over that link, it doesn't seem to answer my question.

Comment: I don't understand why it works when I put  source : [{"label":"Paris - London - Rome","value":"1"},{"label":"Lison - Dublin - Berlin","value":"2"},{"label":"Atena - Paris - Warsaw","value":"4"},{"label":"Moscow - New York - San Francisco","value":"7"}]

Comment: And why it doesn't when I get the JSON from url.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".auto").autocomplete({
    source : [{"label":"Paris - London - Rome","value":"1"},{"label":"Lison - Dublin - Berlin","value":"2"},{"label":"Atena - Paris - Warsaw","value":"4"},{"label":"Moscow - New York - San Francisco","value":"7"}],
    minLength : 2,
    select : function(event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var myArray = ui.item.label.split('-');
        var valor = this.value;
        var elige;
        $.each(myArray, function( index, value ) {
            console.log(value);
            console.log(valor);
            if(value.match(valor)){ 
                elige = value;
            }
        });
        this.value = elige;
        $(this).next().val(ui.item.value);
    }
});
});
```

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/kV4Jn/

Comment: Yes. I know. I specified that if I put     source : [{"label":"Paris - London - Rome","value":"1"},{"label":"Lison - Dublin - Berlin","value":"2"},{"label":"Atena - Paris - Warsaw","value":"4"},{"label":"Moscow - New York - San Francisco","value":"7"}],

Comment: It works with the code above. But if I get the json from a URL it doesn't. It just shows me all options.

Comment: Nope man....i put both "versions" of your code in jsfiddle, neither works...check this: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/LyQgN/ ...that is your working version...not working :)

Comment: That does not making any sense...in my version just the city you are looking is stored in the text value, and wotks for every city....if you choose Rome just Rome is showed in the textbox, if you select Paris, just Paris is showed on the textbox and so on :)